# python | start new thread that will impersonate another uid without affecting main thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, linux-kernel, impersonation

I with to create a new thread which will impersonate to another uid, execute a task and finish, while my main thread will keep is original uid all the time.

impersonation can easily be achieved by using

```
os.setuid(self.impersonation_uid)
```

but how can I make sure that it won't change my original uid from the main thread?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Threads cannot have separate user ids; only processes can. The data structure the kernel uses for process has a user id field, but the thread one doesn't - so, this is an architectural limitation.

Processes are defined by [`task_struct`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/sched.h#L728), which has a `cred` field, pointing to a [`cred`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/cred.h#L110) structure, including uid, gid etc.

Threads are defined by [`thread_info`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h#L56), which doesn't have anything point to user credentials.